# Correctly handle Celery Exceptions using autoretry_for

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, message-queue

I have a celery task which is decorated with `autoretry_for` so that in the event of a known exception, it will retry the task. A dummy version here:

```
class ExpectedException(Exception):
    pass


@app.task(autoretry_for=(ExpectedException,), retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 2, 'countdown': 1})
def decorated_autoretry():
    logging.info(
        "Attempt: {attempt} of {attempts}".format(
            attempt=decorated_autoretry.request.retries, attempts=decorated_autoretry.max_retries
        )
    )
    raise ExpectedException
```

when run gives the following output:

```
[2018-01-30 12:17:31,899: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[9e00f56d-fb90-46db-a735-678fd0b4cb5a]  
[2018-01-30 12:17:31,900: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Attempt: 1 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:17:31,915: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[9e00f56d-fb90-46db-a735-678fd0b4cb5a] retry: Retry in 1s: ExpectedException()
[2018-01-30 12:17:31,915: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[9e00f56d-fb90-46db-a735-678fd0b4cb5a]  ETA:[2018-01-30 12:17:32.901955+00:00] 
[2018-01-30 12:17:33,024: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Attempt: 2 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:17:33,072: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[9e00f56d-fb90-46db-a735-678fd0b4cb5a]  ETA:[2018-01-30 12:17:34.029462+00:00] 
[2018-01-30 12:17:33,072: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[9e00f56d-fb90-46db-a735-678fd0b4cb5a] retry: Retry in 1s: ExpectedException()
[2018-01-30 12:17:34,033: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Attempt: 3 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:17:34,037: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[9e00f56d-fb90-46db-a735-678fd0b4cb5a] raised unexpected: ExpectedException()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greg/gel/interpretation/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 374, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greg/gel/interpretation/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 629, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greg/gel/interpretation/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 474, in run
    raise task.retry(exc=exc, **retry_kwargs)
  File "/home/greg/gel/interpretation/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 669, in retry
    raise_with_context(exc)
  File "/home/greg/gel/interpretation/.env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 472, in run
    return task._orig_run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/greg/gel/interpretation/interpretationAPI/tasks/util_tasks.py", line 25, in decorated_autoretry
    raise ExpectedException
ExpectedException
```

where in the last attempt the `ExpectedException` is raised but Celery regards it as unexpected.

I can explicitly handle the exceptions here:

```
@app.task
def explicit_autoretry():
    logging.info(
        "Attempt: {attempt} of {attempts}".format(
            attempt=explicit_autoretry.request.retries+1, attempts=explicit_autoretry.max_retries
        )
    )
    try:
        raise ExpectedException
    except ExpectedException as e:
        logging.info(msg="Received exception of type: {e_type}".format(e_type=type(e)))
        try:
            explicit_autoretry.retry(countdown=1)
        except MaxRetriesExceededError as e:
            logging.info(msg="Received exception of type: {e_type}".format(e_type=type(e)))
```

which when run gives the following output:

```
[2018-01-30 12:19:45,284: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9]  
[2018-01-30 12:19:45,287: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Attempt: 1 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:19:45,288: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Received exception of type: <class 'interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.ExpectedException'>
[2018-01-30 12:19:45,301: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9] retry: Retry in 1s
[2018-01-30 12:19:45,301: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9]  ETA:[2018-01-30 12:19:46.288992+00:00] 
[2018-01-30 12:19:47,790: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Attempt: 2 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:19:47,792: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Received exception of type: <class 'interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.ExpectedException'>
[2018-01-30 12:19:47,839: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9] retry: Retry in 1s
[2018-01-30 12:19:47,839: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9]  ETA:[2018-01-30 12:19:48.796492+00:00] 
[2018-01-30 12:19:49,789: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Attempt: 3 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:19:49,789: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Received exception of type: <class 'interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.ExpectedException'>
[2018-01-30 12:19:49,791: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9] retry: Retry in 1s
[2018-01-30 12:19:49,791: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9]  ETA:[2018-01-30 12:19:50.790244+00:00] 
[2018-01-30 12:19:51,791: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Attempt: 4 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:19:51,791: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Received exception of type: <class 'interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.ExpectedException'>
[2018-01-30 12:19:51,791: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Received exception of type: <class 'celery.exceptions.MaxRetriesExceededError'>
[2018-01-30 12:19:51,791: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.explicit_autoretry[b1f29107-ac73-401d-b0c3-636e91661ee9] succeeded in 0.00055760199939s: None
```

which correctly deals with each instance of `ExpectedException` and the final `MaxRetriesExceededError`, allowing for graceful error handling.

Is there a way of such error handling while using the `autoretry_for` decorator, minimising the amount of explicit error handling ? I've also tried using the `on_failure` handler but to no avail.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `throws=(ExpectedException,)` to the decorator. 
Modifying the example above:

```
@app.task(throws=(ExpectedException,), autoretry_for=(ExpectedException,), retry_kwargs={'max_retries': 2, 'countdown': 1})
def decorated_autoretry():
    logging.info(
        "Attempt: {attempt} of {attempts}".format(
            attempt=decorated_autoretry.request.retries, attempts=decorated_autoretry.max_retries
        )
    )
    raise ExpectedException
```

will run giving:

```
[2018-01-30 12:43:48,684: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[34de3cb0-9fec-4bc3-a900-c0eb5d8eb5b0]  
[2018-01-30 12:43:48,685: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Attempt: 1 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:43:48,687: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[34de3cb0-9fec-4bc3-a900-c0eb5d8eb5b0] retry: Retry in 1s: ExpectedException()
[2018-01-30 12:43:48,688: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[34de3cb0-9fec-4bc3-a900-c0eb5d8eb5b0]  ETA:[2018-01-30 12:43:49.685804+00:00] 
[2018-01-30 12:43:51,641: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Attempt: 2 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:43:51,643: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[34de3cb0-9fec-4bc3-a900-c0eb5d8eb5b0] retry: Retry in 1s: ExpectedException()
[2018-01-30 12:43:51,643: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[34de3cb0-9fec-4bc3-a900-c0eb5d8eb5b0]  ETA:[2018-01-30 12:43:52.642046+00:00] 
[2018-01-30 12:43:53,459: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Attempt: 3 of 3
[2018-01-30 12:43:53,461: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] Task interpretationAPI.tasks.util_tasks.decorated_autoretry[34de3cb0-9fec-4bc3-a900-c0eb5d8eb5b0] raised expected: ExpectedException()
```

and will exit gracefully, as we can see from the `raised expected: ExpectedException()` part of the message.

Comment: I want to do something different when max retries are exceeded. Ex- Sending a Mail. But adding throws will not solve this issue as I can't intercept the MaxRetriesExceededError

Comment: Can you catch the ExpectedException and then send the email ?